# How to find python scripts by the libraries they use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

Would be really useful for development help. I'm looking for examples of pythons websockets module but I cant find it because everything is called websockets.

Comment: Are you asking how to find Python scripts on the Internet (a Google/search engine question), or how to find them in a directory of files on a hard drive (perhaps writing a script to read .py files and search for `import websockets`)?

Comment: For plenty of examples on python websockets : check https://www.fullstackpython.com/websockets.html